# Execute 3 functions that return true/false and if all return true do something or else, no short circuiting

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators

I have 3 JS functions a() b() c()

I want to execute all 3 and also check if all 3 return true then I want to call function yeah() or else call function boo()

I can use && but it will **short circuit** and may not execute all 3 functions if first or second returns false

So

```
      if(a() && b() && c()) { yeah(); } else { boo(); }
```

wouldn't work!

Can you suggest a better single line code?

Comment: Check out the `&` operator :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a one-liner, you can also use `&` instead of `&&`:

```
if(a() & b() & c()) { yeah(); } else { boo(); }
```

Or you can do this if you want to know exactly how many functions returned true:

```
if(a() + b() + c() == 3) { yeah(); } else { boo(); }
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/DQkpM/1/

Comment: This would certainly work, but the OP did ask for "single line of code".  Presumably they are looking for a shortcut to do this.

Comment: @jfriend00: Thanks, didn't notice that the first time I read it.

Comment: Assuming the functions actually return `true` or `false`, you could get rid of the `~~` since the *toNumber* conversion is performed for you when adding booleans.

Comment: Or a little more compact. `a() & b() & c() ? yeah() : boo();`

Answer (score 1):

A & b & c will do the trick. It will execute all three functions.